# Questions on Yitroh's Advise to Moses on appointing judges

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu, beit-din-court, parashas-yisro

Without further ado:

1. Bney Noah are commanded on establishing a legal system and courts. I would expect Bney Israel in Egypt and through the Exodus to comply with this commandment. **What Chidush did Yitroh advise Moses on establishing Batey Dinim for Israel**, especially after they were commanded Dinim in Marah?
2. Moses was a father of all prophets, spent a total of 80 days studying and mastering Tora and laws with Hashem on Mt. Sinai. Yitro was just a convert, with no Torah background. **So what was the Moses' reason for judging alone and how dare Yitroh to offer Moses an advice**?
3. The Torah says it was Moses' first day of judging people. **How did Yotroh get such a fast impression of an inevitable failure on the very first day, and how did Moses agreed so fast?**
4. When someone wants his advice to be heard and followed, he usually keeps the changes small, like if you want to advise your friend to change his $5000 car, you'd probably offer to buy a $10K or $20K but surely not $500K. Instead of offering to involve Aharon and his sons (5 men), or the Heads of the tribes (12 men) or the Elders (70 men), he offers to jump straight to a total of 77,000 judges. **Is this way of thinking reasonable**?
5. The system offered by Yitroh totally contradicts the Oral Law we have ruled in Sanhedrin, i.g. courts of 3, 23 and 71. **All appointed judges were single judges (דיין יחיד). How come**?
6. Moses prophesied the 77,000 judges. But **did he also prophesied the division of the Israeli nation into tens and fifties and hundreds and thousands**? If no, what's in the name of the judges, if yes, what was the division based on? (A bonus question - the tribes did not count full thousands and even hundreds - did some judges worked with more that one tribe?)
7. *Slightly off-topic and more general question*: **When does Moses decide to act on his own and when he decides to consult Hashem**? Why did he not consult Hashem as he did on other occasions (like Bnot Zlofechad)? What was Hashem's reaction in this case - did He agree?

I am open to adding your questions also. Thank you.

Comment: So the question is, how come Moshe hadn't thought up the idea Yitro came up with, since making courts is one of the Seven Laws of Bnei Noach?

Comment: Right, That's the first question. Moses, however, does not think up, he follows what he was told. I think it is a better description.

Comment: I'd recommend narrowing this question a bit. There's too much on the plate as it stands.

Comment: al thinks a lot (as he is evidently doing in the pic :) so this is just a long string of nice questions. how about splitting them up into well founded questions, instead of an entire introduction to a speculative lecture? (no offence intended, just honest constructive criticism)

Comment: also, didn't you criticize moshe rabbeinu for being a reactive vs. proactive leader?

Comment: Waaaaaay too broad. These are great questions, but it’s too many for one post.

Comment: I suppose that **a true answer will address all of my questions**. I would like to see a whole picture instead of dealing with crumbs. This is a Parasha on its own and  Moses and Yitroh knew what they were doing. I really don't mean getting short excuses on every single point, but one exhaustive answer covering them all (OK, besides the last).

Comment: @heshy This question(s) is a good example of a _seemingly_ reactive behavior of Moses I was asking for. What was he thinking before sitting down? What was his big plan for judging the multimillion nation? How come he changed his mind so quickly by listening to a newly converted idolater?

Comment: @AlBerko see rashi that it was just for a short time, not all day lit. obviously not so many people came. also you are very busy with this converted idolater business. first of all the key word here is converted. second, see rashi beg. of yisro that originally moshe considered it an honor to be the son in law of yisro, he was a great man.