# Yitroh's advice - was every chief a Beis Din on his own?

Tags: halacha-theory, beit-din-court, parashas-yisro

This is a follow-up question on "[Yitrohs-advise-to-moses-on-appointing-judges](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/89081/questions-on-yitrohs-advise-to-moses-on-appointing-judges) [(Shmot 18, 21)](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.18.22?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=he&with=Commentary&lang2=he):

> "...וְשַׂמְתָּ עֲלֵהֶם **שָׂרֵי אֲלָפִים שָׂרֵי מֵאוֹת שָׂרֵי חֲמִשִּׁים וְשָׂרֵי עֲשָׂרֹת׃ וְשָׁפְטוּ אֶת־הָעָם בְּכָל־עֵת** ..."
>
> "Set these over them as **chiefs of thousands, hundreds, fifties, and tens, and let them judge the people at all times.** Have them bring every major dispute to you, but **let them decide every minor dispute themselves.**"

According to the existing Halachah we set up 3 different forms of Beis Din - 71 and 23 for criminal and of 3 for monetary offences. There's is an option for דן יחידי but it is not encouraged.

THe question is how those 78,000 judges were arranged in courts:

- were they all דן יחידי?
- were they grouped in courts of 3 or 23?
- was each one establishing a court by joining two laymen to be 3?